# Why is the program not going through a loop?

Tags: python

I am making a program which checks usernames and passwords from a file, also adds to the file.
But while registering when I try check if the username is already in the file it completely ignores it and goes to the next line. Any way to fix? I had it working before but since I made it a bit more complex it has stopped working.

```
import sys

def login():

    while True:
        
        username = input("Please enter the username: ")
        password = input("Please enter the password: ")
        userpass = (username + ":" + password)
        file = open("UserPass.txt", "r")
        for line in file:
            if userpass in line:
                print("Login Successful!")
                sys.exit()
        print("Incorrect credentials!")
        start()

def register():

    while True:
        
        username = input("Please enter a username: ")
        file = open("UserPass.txt", "a+")
        for line in file:
            if username in line:
                print("That username is already in use!")
                start()
        password = input("Please enter a password: ")
        userpass = (username + ":" + password)
        file.write(userpass + "\n")
        print("Successfully registered!")
        sys.exit()

def start():

    while True:
        
        choice = input("Do you want to login or register?: ")

        if choice == "login":
            login()
            break
        elif choice == "register":
            register()
            break
        else:
            print("Not a valid choice.")

start()
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using `sys.exit()` in both login and register keeping the file open. Close the file using `file.close()`